# How to make a code inside a C++ software communicate with an arduino board?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to track time delays inside a software called OpenVibe, this software is a graphical programming environment which relies on a C++ architecture. every boxes (Hence the Graphical programming) are actually C++ codes. The ones I developed are visual stimulus appearing on the screen (It used a standard GDK drawing approach). However, I want to see the delay between the sending of the information and the actual display on the screen.  Therefore I want to activate a serial port connected to an arduino board during the activation of the box in the software. I intend to send a numerical value that could be read by the arduino board and would light a LED. If I don't have a delay the LED would light up exactly at the same time of the screen display, and I doubt that.

I am not sure of the process to send data to a serial port using C++ while a program is already running.

Thanks in advance.
Tristan

Comment: There are guides on the arduino website for interfacing through C++ (https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows/) but I am not sure if this is at all helpful for OpenVibe.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check if it could work, indeed I don't know if it is possible when it is inside OpenVibe